# MS Excel Sorting by rows but keeping same data in same column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, sorting

I have data like this:

[image: (simplified)]

But want it sorted like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered a [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)? What things have you tried so far, please [edit] your question with this information?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that there is other data in this sheet related to this and all needs to be kept together.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to this site and trying to edit my question but will have to wait until tomorrow to get this done. Perhaps I should delete and try again. :-)

Comment: Never delete, if you need help with writing the question just ask us in [chat]

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I have a solution, I hope it meets your needs. Maybe there is a more clever solution, but at least mine doesn't rely on macros.

In my solution, you will have your original data in one place, and you will need to assign space (either in the original sheet to the right or in a new sheet) where your data will be copied to based on some formulas.

Basically the formula will check each cell in a row for the desired data, and if it finds the data, it will show it. That is, the first cell in the new space will check every cell in your data's first row for an "A", and if it finds one, it will print an A:

```
=IF($A1="A","A",IF($B1="A","A",IF($C1="A","A",IF($D1="A","A",""))))
```

For the new B-column, the first cell would look then like this:

```
=IF($A1="B","B",IF($B1="B","B",IF($C1="B","B",IF($D1="B","B",""))))
```

And the following:

```
=IF($A1="C","C",IF($B1="C","C",IF($C1="C","C",IF($D1="C","C",""))))
=IF($A1="D","D",IF($B1="D","D",IF($C1="D","D",IF($D1="D","D",""))))
=IF($A1="E","E",IF($B1="E","E",IF($C1="E","E",IF($D1="E","E",""))))
=IF($A1="F","F",IF($B1="F","F",IF($C1="F","F",IF($D1="F","F",""))))
```

After you have filled the first row where you want the sorted data to be, you can just extent it down and it will adjust the formulas for the following rows.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think posted data is just an example, hard coding cell values in formulas is really not a good practice.

Comment: You're right. At least the if-true-value should be according to the cell. But original values to check for must be either hard-coded in the formula or in a separate cell.